# How to bind q to close a readonly buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

How do I bind <kbd>q</kbd> to close a read-only buffer forcefully without any promptings?

Fugitive plugin for example does this when you do `:Gst`. In that buffer <kbd>q</kbd> closes everything and returns back to the file. It's a handy feature.

How do I extend this to any RO buffers because it makes sense to bind <kbd>q</kbd> to close it and I don't see why Macros are useful in RO buffers. Also do you have any alternative suggestions for this? I do find myself closing RO buffers so many times with `:close!` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a conditional mapping, see `:help :map-expression`:

```
:nnoremap <expr> q (&readonly ? ':close!<CR>' : 'q')
```

I still wouldn't recommend to overload a command with two such drastically different meanings; how about `<Leader>q` for closing?

Comment: Thanks for the advise , neither do I like overloading , but "q" seems to have no purpose in read only buffers and its very intuitive to use IMHO !

Comment: Do you see a use case where 'q' might be helpful in buffers ? q is to start bind a macro , and have you every stumbled upon using that in RO buffers ? Just curious ?

Comment: Well, you could write a macro to "collect" certain areas by moving and appending into a register. That would be useful for readonly buffers, too.